# Use one controller for routing in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

Here is simple example of creating routes with Angular JS:

```
var EmpApp = angular.module('EmpApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'EmpControllers'
]);

EmpApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/list', {
        templateUrl: 'Employee/list.html',
        controller: 'ListController'
    }).
    when('/create', {
        templateUrl: 'Employee/edit.html',
        controller: 'EditController'
    }).
    when('/edit/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'Employee/edit.html',
        controller: 'EditController'
    }).
    when('/delete/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'Employee/delete.html',
        controller: 'DeleteController'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/list'
    });

}]);
```

Source from [here](http://rohit-developer.blogspot.com/2015/01/crud-using-mvc-web-api-and-angularjs.html)

As you can see there are different controllers for every action (add, delete, etc.)

My question is next : is it possible to create just one controller but with function that has the same logic as in controllers above (Just create controller `EmpCtrl` and add functions `add()`, `delete()` etc.) and apply this functions to routes? Example :

```
$routeProvider.when('/list', {
        templateUrl: 'Employee/list.html',
        controller: 'EmpCtrl' <-- here somehow use EmpCtrl.list()
    }).
    when('/create', {
        templateUrl: 'Employee/edit.html',
        controller: 'EmpCtrl' <-- here somehow use EmpCtrl.add()
    })
```

And if it is possible is it good approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. However I wouldn't say it's a good approach. Controllers are simply meant to take information and bind it to the scope - no more. If two states have the same controller that means they are sharing information, and could probably just be one controller/state instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible to create a single AngularJs controller and assign it to for list,create,update and delete Routes.

Each CRUD function can live inside one controller.
But controller: 'EmpCtrl' <-- here somehow use EmpCtrl.list() this is not possible.
AngularJs  expacts a controller class only.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about `prototypical inheritance`.
Angular's `$scope` inherits `prototypically`. Example with `ui-router`.

Suppose if you have a parent state like:

```
.state(parent, {
  abstract: true,
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.parentMethod = function() {
      console.log("Found on parent")
    }
  }
})
```

And a child state of the above parent like:

```
.state(parent.child, {
  controller: function($scope){
    $scope.parentMethod(); // Implementation at parent state
  }
})
```

The call to `parentMethod` is `bubbled up` from the current point of call. We have called the `parentMethod()` in `parent.child` state. It cant be found there. So it goes up to the parent and tries to invoke `parentMethod`. This is continued until it reaches to `$rootScope`. When the method is not found anywhere you get a `Reference Error`.

If my explanation sounds confusing, google `Prototypical Inheritance and Angular $scope and $rootScope`.